# Store return from a command into a variable in a bat file

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I have a program where I take a list of IPs, run nslookup on them, and then store them into two different files, one where the IP is included, one which just has the output of nslookup.  To cut my calls to nslookup in half, I would like to call it once, store it in a variable, and then write to both files.  But, a simple store doesn't work.

```
set val=nslookup %ip%
```

displays

```
nslookup 127.0.0.1
```

and not the result of running it.

I've found one way to do this this is

```
nslookup %ip% | find "Name"> tempFile
set /P result=<tempFile
```

but I'm now writing to a file and then getting the value back.  For that cost, I might as well call nslookup twice.  It also requires me to pick a single line (which is fine for me this time, but for other cases it may not work).

I've also tried using the for loop trick

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('nslookup %ip% ^| find "Name"') do set name=%%a
```

but this only returns the very last line or the one line I specify with find.  Still better than the previous example as there are no temp files, but still imperfect.

So my question is if there is some better way to store the return value from a command to a variable.

Edit:
Consider

```
nslookup 127.0.0.1
```

which returns

```
Server: fake.com
Address:  0.0.0.0

Name:  localhost
Address:  127.0.0.1
```

Right now, all I want is the name, so returning a single line works for my current batch file.  But what if I also needed to know the server, so I want

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('nslookup 127.0.0.1') do set returnVal=%%a
echo %returnVal%
```

to display

```
Server: fake.com
Address:  0.0.0.0

Name:  localhost
Address:  127.0.0.1
```

where right now it only displays

```
Address:  127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Given the output is two lines (at least) what information are you trying to extract? An example would do fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Batch file below store the four non-empty lines shown by nslookup in an *array* with four elements:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('nslookup 127.0.0.1') do (
   set /A n+=1
   set returnVal[!n!]=%%a
)

rem To show all non-empty lines:
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do echo !returnVal[%%i]!

rem Or:
echo Line with Name: %returnVal[3]%
```

Comment: It seems I'll need to store it in an array then.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 @echo off
 setlocal
 for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in (`nslookup %ip%`) do echo %%a:%%b
```

Comment: `for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ('nslookup 127.0.0.1') do echo %%a:%%b` returns `nslookup 127.0.0.1:`.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You have to use back quotes. That's what usebackq does. It shares the ~ key on the kb. from a cmd prompt read for /? and it explains it towards the bottom.

Comment: Echo produces the correct output, but when I store it, it stores only the last line.

Comment: That makes sense. Var keeps getting overwritten until you're left with the last line. The echo fires off for each iteration which is why it works. If there was a way to insert a newline between variables, set var=!var! newline %%a:%%b would do it but I don't know of any way to insert a carriage return between variables.